# Access a field created by the constructor in an abstract class (Scala)

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that implements one method.

How can I access the parameter `internalValue` (set by the abstract class constructor?)

```
abstract class Value(internalValue:Int) {
    def equal( v:Value ): Boolean

    def notEqual( v:Value ): Boolean = {

        //here I get an error on v.internalValue:
        //"value internalValue is not a member of Value"
        (internalValue != v.internalValue)
    }
}

case class Value1(internalValue:Int) extends Value(internalValue){
    def equal( v:Value1 ): Boolean = {
        //this works correctly
        (internalValue == v.internalValue)
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Define `internalValue` to be `val`:

```
abstract class Value(val internalValue: Int)
```

or if you are concerned about encapsulation (which the name `internalValue` suggests) you can use `private val`:

```
abstract class Value(private val internalValue: Int)
```

Not declaring any modified at all is <del>effectively equivalent (?)</del> similar to `private[this]` which means: *only this particular instance of `Value` can access this private field*.

Comment: I don't think it's equivalent. `private[this]` are stored as private fields of the instances, when constructor parameters are stored only if they are used past construction.

Comment: @paradigmatic: thanks, but it is equivalent in OPs case where constructor parameter is used in some other method, is that right? I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, in that case it should generate a private final field.

Comment: If I change

`abstract class Value(internalValue:Int) {`

to

 `abstract class Value(val internalValue:Int) {`

I get two errors on Value1: 

"
- overriding value internalValue in class Value of type Int; value internalValue needs `override' modifier
- class Value1 needs to be abstract, since method equal in class Value of type (v: Value)Boolean is not defined (Note that Value does not match Value1)
"